# Is there a way to use results from the first mysql query to run the second query using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I have two mysql queries to run. I can only run the second query base on the result i received from the first query.
My problem is i dont know how to pass the result as a parameter to the second query

```
router.post('/member/add', (req, res)=>{
        let ins_company = req.body.ins_company
        let firstname = req.body.firstname
        let othernames = req.body.othernames
        let surname = req.body.surname
        let member_no = req.body.new_member_no
        let status = req.body.card_status
        let card_pin = req.body.card_pin
        let join_date = req.body.join_date_now
        let date_of_birth = req.body.dateofbirth
        let sex = req.body.patient_sex
        let telephone_no = req.body.tel
        let nationality = req.body.patient_nationality
        let employer = req.body.employer
        let employer_id = req.body.employer_id
        let health_plan = req.body.health_plan
        let email = req.body.email
        let relationship = req.body.relationship
        let picpath = req.body.filepath0
        let member_type = req.body.member_type
        let rx_member_id = req.body.rx_member_id
        let member_plan_id = 'SLB Medical Plan'

        let result

        result = db.query("SELECT * FROM company_plan WHERE PlanID = ?",[member_plan_id],(err,row,fields)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Some errors "+ err)
                res.end()
                return
            }

            res.end()
                return
            let member_plan = row[0].Plan

            const queryString = "INSERT INTO patient_info_registration(ins_company,member_plan,surname,firstname) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"
            db.query(queryString, [
                ins_company,
                member_plan,
                surname,
                firstname
            ], (err,row,fields)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Some errors "+ err)
                res.end()
                return
            }
            res.json(row);
        })


        })
        })




    })

    module.exports = router
```

I want to be able to pass the variable member_plan = row[0].Plan to the next query.

Comment: It would be far better to use `INSERT ... SELECT` here in a single statement, so that you can ensure everything is done in one nice transaction automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the return statement and res.end() from :

```
 res.end()
                return
            let member_plan = row[0].Plan
```

and pass the value of member_plan to your second query because this one is in your first callback function.

However i would suggest you to create some function to clarify your code instead of doing everything in the same place.
You can also use Promise or Async/Await instead of callback which is way better for writing a clean code and avoid the "callback hell"

Moreover, you can use destructuring to get all data from req.body as following :

```
let { health_plan, email, relationship, etc... } = req.body;
```

This with create all your variables with the value of req.body.{variableName} inside